# bash shell script not executing in mac

Tags: shell

I have a simple bash script test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is a comment
echo "Hi"
```

It does not execute anything when I try to run ./test.sh

```
$ ./test.sh 
$
```

It comes with empty output. The mac terminal is executing echo commands but not shell script. I am not sure what I am missing. Please suggest.

Comment: It works on my Mac (although I had to do a `chmod ugo+rx ./test.sh` first).    Does the expected output appear if you delete the `# This is a comment` line from the file?

Comment: What  do mean by " mac terminal is executing echo commands but not shell script"?
This script executes correctly when file `test.h` has `exec permissions and outputs error `test.sh: Permission denied` when it has not.

Comment: That's a sh script, not a bash one...

Comment: You need to run it by bash, if you want to have a bash script, i.e. `bash test.sh`.

Answer (score -1):

to execute command file , type sh test.sh

Comment: Won't do. Note that the OP explicitly wants to run it as **bash** command. Admittedly, with this simple example, it does not make a difference, but I think that the OP later wants to extend his script.